# amd pstate performance not working. OS loads 6.5 kernel instead of newer custom kernel i install

Tags: 23.10

When using amd-pstate epp performance, the freqs on my cpu zen3 should stay at 3770 like they do in 22.04 ... but they stay at 29xx like it is "balanced mode".
I have both performance governor in kernel and epp performance hint in profile-daemon, and it still stays 2900.

When i install my custom kernel with my own commits which is 6.6+, the system boots on stock ubuntu kernel despite being older. No such issue on 22.04.
I tried grub customizer to make 6.6+ the top kernel, and even after updating grub, the OS still chooses 6.5.